# react-native-track-player: Foreground service doesn't stop and audio keeps playing after app kill on android

Tags: android, react-native, foreground-service, react-native-track-player

> For a better explanation check this [issue](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/1759). The issue has been
> closed with this [fix](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/pull/1762), but the fix creates another [issue](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/1768)
> which is still open.

react-native-track-player uses foreground service in android to display a notification on with buttons to play/pause audio. However, the issue I am facing is that when I kill the app, the service is killed only the first time. After that if I open the App again, and play an audio, it doesn't stop after app kill and the audio keeps playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is to reset the TrackPlayer on App unmount.

Inside your top level component:

```
useEffect(() =>
 {
   return () => {
     try { TrackPlayer.reset() } catch(){};
   };
 }, []);
```